# PostgreSQL: How to update the date within table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please see image sample data I have.

I want to update the last row `id =5` that it should be the next day of the 2nd to the last row `id=4`.

[image]

How would do that using Postgres?

Comment: Included Image in post so it's shown directly.

Comment: Please do not spam tags.  If this is Postgress SQL question, you can use the postgress & SQL tags - MySQL and SQL Server have nothing to do with this.

Comment: @wmk: im new at this. sorry.

Comment: @MichaelGardner: noted. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I don't know your table name, so I just used 'test'**

For postgres, you would likely want something as follows:

```
UPDATE test SET timestamp = ((SELECT timestamp FROM test WHERE ID=4) + interval '1 day') WHERE ID = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean for this! Sorry if i only provide 1 data to be updated. What if i have a multiple data to be updated? Is it possible?

Comment: @fLen, I am not clear on why you are altering data in this way, why not just enter it correctly in the first place? Honestly, you can probably concoct a function to do this, but I think entering the data correctly would be best.

Comment: We already correct the data. But all wrong inputted data must be correct too, that's why im looking for the query to use.. :(

Comment: @fLen, okay can you give me a more complete picture of how the inaccurate data lies in your table?  Like is there a reliable pattern to discern which rows have bad data in them? Like for example, for IDs starting from 1 and ending at 200, every fourth row needs the timestamp column updated to be one day higher than the timestamp for the row previous to it?   If there is a pattern like this, you can write a function in any language to deal with it (even in postgres if you want)

Comment: we cannot use ID's for this.. :( there are some correct data in the middle of  it.

Comment: So maybe someone else can think of something, but without a reliable way to target the bad data, you'll have to run manual queries to update the bad data as you encounter bad rows. :(